# How to make an Element of a Custom Control Accessible on the View to Subscribe it to a Command?

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls, caliburn.micro

I have a Custom window which has two Buttons. One button is named OKButton and the other is named Cancel Button.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type WindowCustom}">
    "Properties Here"
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type WindowCustom}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                    <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="OK"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel"/> 
"Closing Tags"
```

I have made a Template part with CLR Properties that for the "OKButton" that gets instantiated in the OnApplyTemplate method.

```
 private const string OKButtonPart = "PART_OKButton";

    private Button oKButton;

    public Button OKButton
    {
        get { return oKButton; }
        set
        {
            if (oKButton != null)
            {
                oKButton.Click += OKButtonClick;
                oKButton.Loaded += OKButtonLoaded;
            }

            oKButton = value;
        }
    }
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        OKButton = GetTemplateChild(OKButtonPart) as Button;
    }
```

Assume all other necessary code to make a custom window is there. I wrote several routed commands to make my OKButton do what I want. This is not ideal because my previous implementation of the button used an ActionMessage (Caliburns way of saying Command)

```
<Button>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="SaveHistoryEntry" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

How do I access my control via XAML to add it to the action message? 
What I can do is write the name of my button control on the custom window.

```
<lc:WindowCustom OKButton="">
```

I do not know what to do from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a dependency property to your `WindowCustom` class:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty OkCommandProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("OkCommand", typeof(ICommand),
     typeof(CustomWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

public ICommand OkCommand
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(OkCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(OkCommandProperty, value); }
}
```

...and bind the `Command` property of the `Button` in the `ControlTemplate` to this one:

```
<Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="OK" Command="{Binding OkCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

You could then set or bind the dependency property of the window to any `ICommand` source property as usual:

```
<lc:WindowCustom OkCommand="{Binding YourViewModelCommandProperty}">
```

The command will be invoked when the `Button` is clicked. You can of course do the same thing for the cancel `Button`. Just add another dependency property.

Comment: I will post my implementation with caliburn shortly. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 2):

This answer is targeted at **Caliburn Users** that want to use the ActionMessage functionality on their custom controls. 
The button that lies on my custom window looks like this

```
<lc:ButtonCustom x:Name="PART_OKButton">
             <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="{Binding OkCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                 </i:EventTrigger>
              </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </lc:ButtonCustom>
```

The C# Code on the CustomWindow is almost Identical to the Answer from mm8.

```
public string OkCommand
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(OkCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OkCommandProperty, value); }
    }



public static readonly DependencyProperty OkCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OkCommand", typeof(string), typeof(WindowCustom), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
```

I changed the ICommand to a String Datatype, since the ActionMessage accepts a string.

Finally on the window I assign the Action I want to the action message.

```
<lc:WindowCustom <!--xmlns tags and other dependency proerties-->
    OkCommand="SaveHistoryEntry">
```

It Works!